# Displaying a HALCON HImage in QT

Tags: c++, qt, halcon

I am trying to display an HImage in a QT graphicsview object using c++. Can anyone please point me in the right direction? I haven't been able to find any clues on the internet so far.

Comment: What have you tried? What specific issue you have? What doesn't work?

Comment: This [link](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/search-results.html?q=display%20image) seems to be a good start.

Answer (score 5):

There is a standard example showing the usage of HALCON in Qt. It shows how a qhalconwidget could be implemented to handle iconic objects.

The example can be found here (after installing HALCON): %HALCONEXAMPLES%\cpp\qt\matching